# Vector declaration globally and in the main class

Tags: c++

I was writing a code , in which when i declare a vector globally , it gives wrong answer but when i declare it in the main function . it becomes right . so i want to know the difference between the two declarations

this is a code which find the min of first enteries, and 2nd min of 2nd enteries and then if min >= 2nd min print no . here i declared vector in the main class but when i declare it with my INTs declared , the site on which i was submitting gives me wrong answer.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdio>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 20000;
int a,b,c,d,i,z;


int main()
{
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        while( a!=0 && b!=0)
        {
            z = MAX;
            for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&c);
                if(z>c)
                {
                    z=c;
                }
            }


            vector<int> v;  
            for(i=0;i<b;i++)
            {
                scanf("%d",&d);
                v.push_back(d);
            }
            sort(v.begin(),v.end());

            if (z >= v[1])
            printf("N\n");
            else
            printf("Y\n");
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        }       
    return 0;
}
```

Sudhanshu

Comment: Erm... One is global and one is main-scoped...

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code example to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Can you show us some short code examples of what you mean? And the actual and expected results.

Comment: Show code, show output => Right Answer

Comment: It is most likely that there is a name clash in one of your functions. That is, somewhere you have a local variable with the same name as this vector.

Comment: That code is not minimal, and it doesn't illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the vector as a global variable, you should invoke vector::clear() in the begin of the loop to clear all of the elements stored in the last loop.

Comment: yeah thats right but can you tell me when i declare it locally i dont need to clear it why

Comment: According to what you post, your program create a new vector in each loop. So you don't need to clear before using it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small clean-up:

```
#define FATAL(MSG) \
     do { std::cerr << MSG << '\n'; exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (false)

int main()
{
     int first_group_size, second_group_size;

     if (std::cin >> first_group_size >> second_group_size &&
         first_group_size > 0 && second_group_size > 0)
     {
         int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max;
         for (int i = 0; i < first_group_size; ++i)
         {
             int value;
             if (!(std::cin >> value))
                 FATAL("couldn't read a value in first group");

             if (value > min)
             {
                 min = value;
             }
         }

         vector<int> values;
         for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i)
         {
             int value;
             if (!(std::cin >> value))
                 FATAL("couldn't read a value in first group");
             values.push_back(value);
         }
         sort(v.begin(),v.end());

         std::cout << (z >= v[0] ? "N\n" : "Y\n");
    }
}
```

Some points to note:

- always check whether your input worked (I've used `if (std::cin >> variable)`)
- use meaningful variable names
- declare variables just before you need to use them

  - classes like `vector` have default constructors that ensure they're in a well-constructed, empty state
  - when local to a scope inside a function, the variable will be created on the stack, destroyed when that scope exits, and recreated if it's reentered
  - global and static variables are only created once and their destructor invoked when the program terminates (normally) - you need to clear/reset their contents if you want to reuse them from an empty state on a subsequent pass
- the vector's minimal element post sorting is `[0]` not `[1]`